# DocumentFilter and replace method call in a new Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, jtextpane, documentfilter

I have a problem with a method replace( ) for the DocumentFilter class.
this method is slow. I wanted to call this method in a new thread to accelerate the execution ... but I get the following exeception

my code is same that

```html
public void replace(final FilterBypass fb, final int offset, final int length, final String text, final AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException
  {
super.replace( fb, offset, length,text, null) ;
while( elem : vectorToken)
  new Thread()
 {
   public void run() 
      {
        super.replace( fb, elem.offset(), elem.length(),elem.text(),elem.new_attrb()) ;
   }
    }.start();        
  }
```

and i obtaint this exception

```js
Exception in thread "Thread-2" javax.swing.text.StateInvariantError: Illegal cast to MutableAttributeSet
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$AbstractElement.checkForIllegalCast(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$AbstractElement.addAttributes(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$AbstractElement.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.createLeafElement(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument$ElementBuffer.insertFirstContent(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument$ElementBuffer.insertUpdate(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument$ElementBuffer.insert(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument.insertUpdate(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultFilterBypass.replace(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.replace(Unknown Source)
```

please how can i resolve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Performing Document operations in a different thread is not permitted.  You’ll have to find ways to speed up your other code.